# Mocking a webservice CalloutException for a SOAP Fault

Tags: webservices, webservicemock

I have a mock class for a web service that implements [WebServiceMock](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_CSH.htm#apex_interface_webservicemock.htm).

With some requests the actual web service being mocked will return a SOAP Fault that results in a System.CalloutException in Apex. E.g. passing in an invalid external ID.

**How can I mock the SOAP fault response that results in a CalloutException?**

I have code that catches these exceptions that I'd like to test using the mock. I'd prefer not to insert special test cases in the actual code using `Test.isRunningTest()` to simulate the response.

A sample response from the web service looks like:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <s:Fault>
         <faultcode>s:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">Validation Error(s) occurred during Foo Get.</faultstring>
      </s:Fault>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I cannot throw a new instance of System.CalloutException. Doing so gives the error:

> Type cannot be constructed: System.CalloutException

I cannot extend System.CalloutExceptions. The compiler gives me the error:

> LocalCalloutException: Non-virtual and non-abstract type cannot be extended: System.CalloutException

Usually I would put an instance of the class specified in the `responseType` parameter into the `response` parameter dictionary with the key 'response_x'. I tried switching this out with a SOAP fault:

```
response.put('response_x', '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><s:Fault><faultcode>s:Client</faultcode><faultstring xml:lang="en-US">Validation Error(s) occurred during Foo Get.</faultstring></s:Fault></s:Body></s:Envelope>');
```

This resulted in a (here `FooBar_element` is the type specified in `responseType`):

> System.TypeException: Collection store exception putting String into MAP<String,FooBar_element>

Comment: You just have to return a regular soap fault, I think. Generate the appropriate xml for a soap fault, and the platform should translate this into a thrown soap fault in the code being tested.

Comment: @sfdcfox Usually I would put an instance of the class specified in the `responseType` parameter into the `response` parameter dictionary with the key 'response_x'. Short of throwing an exception that dictionary seems to be the only output mechanism. I'll see if I can put a SOAP fault into it.

Comment: Can you add FooBar_element.class?

Comment: @Torsen `FooBar_element` here will be an arbitrary inner apex class that Wsdl2Apex generated for the SOAP response. It will have members to hold the data, plus a corresponding `membername_type_info` String[]. There will also be string[] for  apex_schema_type_info and field_order_type_info. That's about it. There is no inheritance involved.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's possible to scaffold a `System.CalloutException` by deserializing it into existence or instantiating it with the type. Then you can throw it in your mock:

[Adrian Larson](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2995/adrian-larson) notes that as of API v36.0 you can just construct them :-)

```
@TestVisible class ResponseMock implements WebServiceMock {
    public void doInvoke(
        Object stub,
        Object request,
        Map<String, Object> response,
        String endpoint,
        String soapAction,
        String requestName,
        String responseNs,
        String responseName,
        String responseType
    ) {
        CalloutException e = new CalloutException();
        e.setMessage('Validation Error(s) occurred during Foo Get.');
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Inject it into your test with the normal HTTP mock method:

```
Test.setMock(WebServiceMock.class, new ResponseMock());
client.doTheCallout();
```

Comment: Brilliant! I wonder what other troublesome classes can be constructed that way?

Comment: Wow...I thought it was impossible to `throw` most standard `Exceptions`. Mind = blown.

Comment: It looks like the system is actually allowing the empty constructor, so no need for casting. I wonder if they loosened this up recently?

Answer (score 14):

Just extending the findings of @mattandneil. Not trying to steal any thunder, but this is too long to be a comment.

In [Creating Custom Exceptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/apex7_5.htm), the documentation still claims:

> Since you can’t throw built-in Apex exceptions but can only catch them, you can create custom exceptions to throw in your methods.

Despite this assertion, the compiler now allows built-in `Exception` types to be constructed. I confirmed through `Execute Anonymous` with the following snippet:

```
try
{
    CalloutException e = new CalloutException();
    e.setMessage('This is a constructed exception!');
    throw e;
}
catch (Exception pokemon)
{
    system.debug(pokemon);
}
```

I went through the whole [list](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm) and what do you know? The following types can all be constructed and thrown:

- AsyncException
- CalloutException
- DmlException
- EmailException
- ExternalObjectException
- InvalidParameterValueException
- LimitException (though it still can't be caught)
- JSONException
- ListException
- MathException
- NoAccessException
- NoDataFoundException
- NoSuchElementException
- NullPointerException
- QueryException
- RequiredFeatureMissingException
- SearchException
- SecurityException
- SerializationException
- SObjectException
- StringException
- TypeException
- VisualforceException
- XmlException

Answer (score 0):

I guess all you need to do is create a custom exception which inherits System.CalloutException. System exception cannot be thrown but their sub classes can.

Comment: Nice idea. I tried extending System.CalloutException. It won't compile: `LocalCalloutException: Non-virtual and non-abstract type cannot be extended: System.CalloutException`

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize that issue. I tried but didn't figure out a way solving that..