# Can Built-In Exceptions Be Thrown?

Tags: apex, exception

In [Creating Custom Exceptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_exception_custom.htm), the documentation still claims:

> Since you can’t throw built-in Apex exceptions but can only catch them, you can create custom exceptions to throw in your methods.

Is it still true that built-in `Exception` types cannot be thrown?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

As far as I know, @mattandneil was the first to discover this change in [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41360/mocking-a-webservice-calloutexception-for-a-soap-fault/111166#111166) to a question by @DanielBallinger.

Despite the documentation's claims to the contrary, the compiler now allows built-in `Exception` types to be constructed. I confirmed through `Execute Anonymous` with the following snippet:

```
try
{
    CalloutException e = new CalloutException();
    e.setMessage('This is a constructed exception!');
    throw e;
}
catch (Exception pokemon)
{ // gotta catch em all!
    system.debug(pokemon);
}
```

I went through the whole [list](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm) and what do you know? The following types can all be constructed and thrown:

- AsyncException
- CalloutException
- DmlException
- EmailException
- ExternalObjectException
- InvalidParameterValueException
- LimitException (though it still can't be caught)
- JSONException
- ListException
- MathException
- NoAccessException
- NoDataFoundException
- NoSuchElementException
- NullPointerException
- QueryException
- RequiredFeatureMissingException
- SearchException
- SecurityException
- SerializationException
- SObjectException
- StringException
- TypeException
- VisualforceException
- XmlException

I must admit it feels weird that you can `throw new LimitException()`. I submitted Feedback on the linked documentation requesting that they update their content.

Comment: +1 for "well way cool" - I recall elaborate workarounds I made to simulate CalloutException to test HttpRequest timeout/retry logic -- did you post feedback to the doc page?

Comment: Such a dirty question and answer combo, but i love it. Excellent discovery that warrants the combo.

Comment: What is the constructor for InvalidParameterValueException?  Trying to instantiate it with no-arg or (String) constructor causes a compile time error.

Comment: @ktbiz The empty constructor worked when I originally wrote this question. That sounds like a good new question for you to ask if that is no longer the case!

Comment: Apparently InvalidParameterValueException has a 2 string constructor.  e.g.  `new InvalidParameterValueException('foo', 'bar');`.

Comment: This is awesome because this lets me create a contrived method for getting around the STUPID limit on the length of log files.  Bless you!

Comment: Here are a couple of uncatchable system exceptions that you can also construct and throw: `FinalException`, and `AssertException` (which can officially be thrown by calling any flavor of `System.assert(...)`).