# Rethrowing an exception is missing the stackTraceString

Tags: apex, exception, custom-exception

I have code that is wrapped into a main `try-catch` block and then inside of that I have another `try-catch` which I am using for a specific use case. If the inner `try-catch` gets triggered I then use a custom exception to re-throw the caught exception. However re-throwing the exception loses its stackTrace **unless** I invoke the `getStackTraceString()` method.

Here's what I have:

```
public class myClass {
    public myClass() {}

    public void someMethod() {
        try {
        // some code
            try {
                // more code
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                String additionalDescription = 'something';
                throw new myClassException(additionalDescription, ex);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            system.debug('getStackTraceString is ' + ex.getStackTraceString());
        }
    }
    public class myClassException extends Exception {}
}
```

In this case the `ex.getStackTraceString()` comes in as blank. I get `Caused by ()`.

However if I invoke `ex.getStackTraceString()` in the inner `catch` block then the other `catch` block can see the stack trace as well.

Here's an example when the stack trace is visible to the outer `catch`.

```
public class myClass {
    public myClass() {}

    public void someMethod() {
        try {
        // some code
            try {
                // more code
            } catch (Exception ex) {

                // Just invoking this method without debugging it 
                // or anything else allows the outer catch to read the trace as well. 
                ex.getStackTraceString();


                String additionalDescription = 'something';
                throw new myClassException(additionalDescription, ex);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            system.debug('getStackTraceString is ' + ex.getStackTraceString());
        }
    }
    public class myClassException extends Exception {}
}
```

Any ideas why? This class gets invoked by a trigger if that matters.

Comment: Could be possibly related to this [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008dVIAAY&title=exception-getstacktracestring-does-not-work-for-custom-exceptions-with-spring-16). However the issue description does not have a workaround, whereas you seem to have one.

Comment: Does the Exception cross the trigger boundary? E.g. are you doing something like `try { insert records; } catch(MyClassException e) { ... }`?

Comment: @sfdcfox No, I am not. Just querying for objects but not modifying them.

Comment: @JayantDas Thanks for sharing, it seems like the same thing.

Comment: @Arthlete that was the first result returned when I did a web search :) You should in fact reach out to support and let them know that there's indeed a workaround as you found out, so that they can update the issue. I was able to replicate the behavior as you mentioned. I have seen such weird behavior at times with the platform where just making a method call resolves, one of such that we experienced made to this [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008fb7QAA&title=trigger-oldmap-trigger-new-are-returning-the-same-information-on-after-update-trigger).

Comment: @JayantDas Any idea how to reach out to them? I would like to but have no idea how.

Comment: @Arthlete I can think by contacting your Salesforce account executive. Opening a Support Case if you have Premium Support available. I could only think these two. Or may be a tweet to *salesforcedevs* or *asksalesforce* (not sure if its the right channel though) with details.

Comment: see [clever workaround](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/263617/2602)