# Apex InvalidParameterValueException class constructor parameters?

Tags: apex, exception

What are the constructor parameters for the InvalidParameterValueException class?

```
InvalidParameterValueException e = new InvalidParameterValueException('param1', 'param2');
e.setMessage('parameter bookId is null');
```

What are `param1` and `param2` ?

I cannot find any detailed documentation, there only seems to be [Exception Class and Built-In Exceptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm) article in the Apex Developer Guide.

FYI - I am throwing standard built-in exceptions, because I read [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/111419/can-built-in-exceptions-be-thrown) it was OK these days.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's Java, not Apex, but **[here was some documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/websphere-commerce/7.0.0?topic=SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.api.doc/com/ibm/commerce/exception/InvalidParameterValueException.htm)** (since removed) on *a version* of `InvalidParameterValueException` which suggests the **first argument is the name of the parameter, and the second is its value**:

> **Field Summary**
>
> Fields
>
> ```
> |============================================================|
> |    Modifier and Type         |    Field and Description    |
> |==============================|=============================|
> |    static java.lang.String   |    PARAM_NAME               |
> |                              |    The default value of     |
> |                              |    the parameter name.      |
> |------------------------------------------------------------|
> |    static java.lang.String   |    PARAM_VAL                |
> |                              |    The default value of     |
> |                              |    the parameter value.     |
> |============================================================|
> ```

Comment: Thanks, as a rule of thumb should I fall back to Java documentation if I cannot find any decent Apex documentation, or is that not a reliable strategy?

Comment: It's a very case-by-case kind of thing. Like date formatting it's almost exact. Exceptions seem similar. But other functionality may not translate as well.

Answer (score 2):

I use the first param as the name of the method being called and the second for the parameter value that's invalid. In other languages that's super useful for debug purposes. However, if you do a `System.debug(e);` in your code you'll notice it just prints *Script-thrown exception*. So I'm not sure how helpful the two parameters really are here. I always add an additional line as well:

`ex.setMessage('ABC is not valid for XYZ');`

to help with actual debugging.

But I still use method name & variable value out of habit (and the hope that in later versions the toString will be overridden to be more useful).

Comment: Thanks, I was also using `setMessage('useful message')` but really wanted to know what the parameters were.